# When viewing iOS crash reports, how do swizzled methods appear in the stack trace?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

When viewing iOS crash reports, do swizzled methods appear with the name of the swizzled method or the regular method name?

For example, if I swizzle viewDidLoad with swizzViewDidLoad which method name will appear in the stack trace of a crash report?

Answer (score 0):

`swizzViewDidLoad` will appear in the stack trace.

this is a demo stack trace that swizzled `viewDidAppear`:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: are you sure? do you have any reference or screen shot for that?

Comment: yes, this is a demo stack trace that swizzled `viewDidAppear`. 
[Screenshot](http://o1t4031pq.qnssl.com/16-8-17/32310984.jpg)